# Printing Div with Jquery, but don't print it all

Tags: jquery

I'm using this script, found on StackOverflow, to print a div with all contents.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#printmodal').click(function(){

        // variables
        var contents = $('#content').html();
        var frame = $('#printframe')[0].contentWindow.document;

    // show the modal div
    $('#modal').css({'display':'block'});

        // open the frame document and add the contents
        frame.open();
        frame.write(contents);
        frame.close();

        //Hide all 'noprint' elements
        $(".noprint").css("display","none");

        // print just the modal div
        $('#printframe')[0].contentWindow.print();

        // hide the modal div
        $('#modal').css({'display':'none'});
    });
});
</script>
```

However, there are some elements I don't want to print, ie; buttons and such.  For these elements, they have been given the classname of 'noprint'.  I have a media="print" css, but using the above function does not work.  noprint elements are still printing.  I tried adding the $(".noprint").css("display", "none"); function, but it still prints those elements.  Does anyone know of a way I can make certain elements not print while using the above function?

Comment: Can you produce a jsFiddle so we can better understand your problem?

Comment: can you post the html also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery by default queries only the `document` from the `window` where it has been included, not descendant `iframe`'s documents. You can remedy that by setting a `context` to your selector:

```
$(".noprint", frame).css("display","none");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pEgDj/1/)

#### *Reference*

- [`jQuery( selector [, context ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

Comment: Thanks Fabricio! This did the trick!  I appreciate your time in posting some help.